# Troubleshooting Error in iOSSnapshotTestCase

Tags: unit-testing, fbsnapshottestcase

I've specified the example keys and values in the run scheme's environment variables, run the tests in record mode and then with record mode off.

Still, I'm getting the error "/Users/xqc/Library/Mobile Documents/comappleCloudDocs/Xcode Projects & Resources/Snapshot/SnapshotTests/SettingsVCSnapshotTests.swift:26: error: -[SnapshotTests.SettingsVCSnapshotTests test_example] : failed - Snapshot comparison failed: Optional(Error Domain=FBSnapshotTestControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to load reference image." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Reference image not found. You need to run the test in record mode, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to load reference image., FBReferenceImageFilePathKey=/Users/xqc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A5B479B7-4DF1-B030-05CAF050B00C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/629A7F7C-4264-B830/Snapshot.app/PlugIns/SnapshotTests.xctest/ReferenceImages_64/SnapshotTests.SettingsVCSnapshotTests/test_example@3x.png})"

```
import iOSSnapshotTestCase
@testable import Snapshot

final class SettingsVCSnapshotTests: FBSnapshotTestCase {
    private var sut: SettingsVC!
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        recordMode = false
        sut = SettingsVC()
    }
    
    override func tearDown() {
        sut = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }
    
    func test_example() {
        FBSnapshotVerifyViewController(sut)
    }
}
```

What can I do to figure out the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it: https://github.com/uber/ios-snapshot-test-case/issues/191

When using test plans, the environment variables should be set from the test plan configuration.